# How can build downloader in UWP?

Tags: download, background, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to build downloader in UWP. I stuck at a point. I want to download multiple files at a same time there will be pause/cancel button for every download. I am adding new progressbar and cancel button dynamically in stackpannel. How can create methods for cancel/pause buttons of new download?
Overall what will the best approach to achieve my task?
Thank for your attention in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers it should help to get started